# How to do Umbraco8 backoffice Login/Authentication using c# dotnet?

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, umbraco8

I'm trying to login a user into Umbraco Backoffice using c# with the user credentials. Although http://24days.in/umbraco-cms/2015/extending-membership/ gives about members login  which is not i'm looking for as Member login won't let us access Umbraco Back Office.

I need a way to authenticate Umbraco user using c# dotnet

Ideas are much apprecicated .. thanks all

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why do you need to log in?

Comment: Why can't you use the built-in login functionality provided by Umbraco out of the box? This allows you to create users with different roles and even custom groups.

Comment: Assume you have your own user base and need to have access level to backoffice the same way the users created in umbraco backoffice does. Then you will have to authenticate user in your own portal and with these creds try to authorize the Umbraco backoffice  services .--- Simpler terms ( External authenticated and authorized  user .. trying to edit/create pages of umbraco backoffice)